# I rooted my phone, but I never flashed the ROM and I never flashed the recovery, then I unrooted it. Can you tell its been rooted?

Tags: unrooting

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Pocket (GT-S5300) which has Android Gingerbread 2.3.6.
I rooted the phone by applying update.zip through the recovery console.
I installed titanium backup free, and ROM manager free, but quickly uninstalled them after I saw that I did not really need them on this phone.
I never installed clockwork recovery, i never flashed anything.
I then unrooted the phone by repeating the steps I did to root, using the unroot.zip (renaming first to update.zip)
That worked and Superuser app was removed after reboot.

Now what I want to know is....can Samsung tell my phone has been rooted?
If so, what can I do to remove any trace of it?

Thank you. I know this question has been asked before and answered but I could not find an answer which dealt specifically with my situation where nothing was ever flashed.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **yes**. You should make sure your bootloader is **locked** by executing `fastboot oem lock` in your command line while your device is in fastboot (**Home** + **Power** + **Volume+** for your specific device). Once your bootloader is locked it will be as if you never rooted your device. Once this is all done, you will regain your warranty which would otherwise be voided if you had left the bootloader unlocked.

Comment: Fastboot? I'm confused. When I hold Home + Power + Volume+, I go into recovery mode and there is no command line.
Do Samsung devices have fastboot?

Comment: From recovery mode you then go into fast boot. By command line I meant the terminal on your computer.